# What does "An experiment performed with certainty has results with uncertainty." mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurements

A physics book says:

> An experiment performed with certainty has results with uncertainty.

What does this mean?

Comment: No measurement is perfect. You may indeed know exactly what experiment you performed (or think you do!), but you can't get around measurement precision, accuracy, and uncertainty issues.

Comment: @Jon Custer but the assumption of Unique's textbook is exactly that the measurement is perfect. And while this can never be achieved, as you already stated, thinking about this theoretical perfect measurement helps us get insight into QM. I refer to my answer of this question.

Comment: It would be good to know the context of this sentence (where in the book it appears?) It could also be a way of expressing the importance of always including the uncertainties associated with any measured value.

Comment: Would you happen to recall which book this was, and which page it appeared on?  It's usually nice to be able to provide the source of a quote.  A bit more of the text around it can be useful for establishing context, too, even if you're specifically interested in just that particular part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This statement makes sense in the realm of quantum mechanics and more advanced quantum theories.**

Given an ideal device to measure the state of some particle, the result of the measurement will still be non-definitive. If you would repeat the same measurement with the same ideal device you could still get a different result. One popular demonstration is the Stern-Gerlach-Experiment.

This uncertainty does not come from the device of measurement but is of more fundamental nature. It's an axiom of these theories, that the physical state of the particle itself is uncertain. Think of it like this: As long as a particle is not observed it is in the superposition of multiple states. In the instance of observation the particle collapses in one single determined state, the measured state. Which of these states this is, is not clear before the measurement. But there is a predetermined state, that it's most likely going to collapse in. The uncertainty your book refers to is a measure for the fluctuation of collapses around this most probable state.

**This uncertainty has nothing to do with the device of measurement and the associated uncertainties.**